# Date should not be older than 1 year from current date (Today's date) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement where I need to find the date entered in the textfield should not be older than 1 year from current date. I have coded for the former one but for the latter requirement I could not do it.

```
   function validateNetworthDate() {

        var netWorthFlag = $("#NetworthDate").val();
        //netWorthFlag is coming( the date we entered) : "15/01/2015"

         var errorMsg='';

        var currentTime = new Date();
        var currentDay = currentTime.getDate();
        var currentMonth = currentTime.getMonth()+1; //As January is 0!
        var currentYear = currentTime.getFullYear();
        if(currentDay<10) {
            currentDay='0'+currentDay
        } 
        if(currentMonth<10) {
            currentMonth='0'+currentMonth
        } 


        var enteredDay=netWorthFlag.substr(0,2);
        var enteredMonth=netWorthFlag.substr(3,2);
        var enteredYear=netWorthFlag.substr(6,4);

        var enteredDateFormat=enteredYear+'/'+enteredMonth+'/'+enteredDay;

       //Now entered date should be : "2015/01/15"


        var enDate = new Date(enteredDateFormat);
        var compDate = currentTime - enDate;
        if (compDate<0)
        {
            errorMsg="Future Date not allowed.";
        }
        //Can you please suggest that what should I write here to do validation that Date should not be older than 1 year from current date (Today's date) 
    }
```

Comment: Use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) `if (moment().diff(moment(netWorthFlag, "DD/MM/YYYY"), "years") < 1) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check it out here:

https://jsfiddle.net/v63u7ksf/

```
    var yearAgoTime = new Date().setFullYear(currentTime.getFullYear()-1);


    var compDate2 = enDate - yearAgoTime;
    if (compDate2<0)
    {
        errorMsg="More than 1 year ago not allowed.";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, after getting the string from the input, you can call a function as,

```js
function dateDiff(entereddate) {
  one_year_next_date = new Date(new Date().setYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1))
  entereddate = new Date(entereddate);
  return (one_year_next_date.getTime() - entereddate.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 // diff in days
}

var netWorthFlag = $("#NetworthDate").val();

date_difference = dateDiff(netWorthFlag); /* your input entered date */
/* eg: dateDiff("02/16/2015");  */(check date format ("02/16/2015"))
```

This returns the difference in the dates as number of days.

Then you can write your condition,

```js
if(date_difference > 365(/* 366 */))
  /**** You can even check the leap year of entered date, or next years date ****/
  {
    /**** do your stuff ****/
  } 
else
  {
    /**** do your stuff ****/
  }
```

You can even check the leap year here, taking the year from that date.(check date format ("02/16/2015"))

Comment: hai(@danish), try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check diff yourself as suggested by others, however, I would suggest you to use `moment.js` for date time processing. Its very handy.