# Date coming across as American Format even when explicitly told to use UK

Tags: javascript

I found an earlier question regarding pulling up dates that are marked as future here ([Date should not be older than 1 year from current date (Today's date) in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449408/date-should-not-be-older-than-1-year-from-current-date-todays-date-in-javascr?rq=1))

This works great and is a great piece of work. The issue I'm having is the software we use tries to force everything to use USA date format and we're based in UK. This is fine, I can change the code to mark down as the correct date format for todays date (and it recognises it as UK! ... and I change the input date and it recognises it as GMT!. Great, that means it works right?)

No such luck. Whenever I select for example 06/05/2020 it marks it as 5th June. Even though it looks like all the dates are being marked to grab the UK date based on the input. (keep in mind, it's doing that for todays date). I think my confusion is coming because the console.log error is this

"This is enDateFri Jun 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)" When inputting 06/05/2020. It recognises it as GMT but not as the UK date? I did use the setlocale function to see if it made any difference but no such luck.

```js
function validateNetworthDate() {

    var dateValue = $(".eyeTest input").val();



    var currentTime = new Date();
    var currentDay = currentTime.getDate();
    var currentMonth = currentTime.getMonth() + 1; //As January is 0!
    var currentYear = currentTime.getFullYear();
    if (currentDay < 10) {
        currentDay = '0' + currentDay
    }
    if (currentMonth < 10) {
        currentMonth = '0' + currentMonth
    }


    var enteredDay = dateValue.substr(0, 2);
    var enteredMonth = dateValue.substr(3, 2);
    var enteredYear = dateValue.substr(6, 4);


    var enteredDateFormat = enteredDay + '/' + enteredMonth + '/' + enteredYear;
    console.log(enteredDateFormat)

    // var enteredDateFormat=dateValue;
    //console.log("This is entered date format " + enteredDateFormat);

    var enDate = new Date(enteredDateFormat);

    var yearAgoTime = new Date().setFullYear(currentTime.getFullYear() - 2);

    //console.log(yearAgoTime)

    var compDate = currentTime - enDate;

    console.log("This is enDate " + enDate)
    if (compDate < 0) {

        console.log("future date not allowed");
        alert("future date not allowed");
        $('.eyeTest input').addClass('numNeg');

    }
    else {
        $('.eyeTest input').removeClass('numNeg');
        $('.eyeTest input').addClass('numPos');
    }
    var compDate2 = enDate - yearAgoTime;
    if (compDate2 < 0) {

        console.log("More than 2 year ago not allowed.");
        alert("Eye Test must be no more than 2 years ago");
        $('.eyeTest input').addClass('numNeg');

    }
    else {
        $('.eyeTest input').removeClass('numNeg');
        $('.eyeTest input').addClass('numPos');
    }

}
```

Comment: Quick fix: `var enteredDateFormat = enteredYear + "-" + enteredMonth + '-' + enteredDay;`

Comment: I'm guessing this worked because - The system was looking for a readable format(US to parse into the date) rather than what I was doing going from UK format to UK format? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it parsed the string as US date. Btw, this entire approach seems pretty convoluted and error-prone; what exactly is returned by `$(".eyeTest input").val()`?

Comment: For reference; This is script put into an ECM system front end. There's a lot more going on in the backend that actually handles validation etc and for someone like me who maybe does programming once a year this is pretty much all that is required. The validation goes on elsewhere. I agree that it's awful.

Comment: I understand, but I'd still like to know what `$(".eyeTest input").val()` returns?

Comment: $(".eyeTest input").val() . this returns the UK format (which why I was confused that it was reading it as US.). So the input looked like 06/05/2020. That's why I did the extra validation to make sure hte format was day/month/year - this is the part we changed to US format.